# Define outlook as a default email in word program

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

For some reason my MS Word does not open my Outlook to send mail, but and another program.

How can I define Word to send mail through Outlook?

I am using Office 2010

Answer (score 2):

#### Make Outlook the default program for email messages, contacts, and calendar

> Many programs can send information as an email message. For example,
>   you can send a spreadsheet to a mail recipient in Microsoft Excel, or
>   click an email link on a webpage. If you have more than one email
>   application on your computer, the only way to make sure these actions
>   use a particular application, such as Outlook, is to set it as your
>   default program.
>
> The following steps set Microsoft Outlook 2010 as your default mail
>   program.
>
> 1. Click the File tab.
> 2. Click Options.
> 3. Under Start up options, select the Make Outlook the default program for E-mail, Contacts, and Calendar check box.
>
> Note:
>
> - To send messages, an email account must be added and
>     configured in your Outlook profile

Source [Make Outlook the default program for email messages, contacts, and calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/make-outlook-the-default-program-for-email-messages-contacts-and-calendar-HP010355552.aspx)

---

#### Change the default e‑mail program

> Though Windows Mail is used as the default e‑mail program by web
>   browsers and other programs that support sending e‑mail, you can
>   choose a different e‑mail program as the default. If you decide you
>   want to change the default e‑mail program back to Windows Mail, you
>   can do so at any time.
>
> 1. Open Default Programs by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Default Programs.
> 2. Click Set your default programs.
> 3. Under Programs, click the e‑mail program you'd like to use, and then click Set this program as default.
> 4. Click OK.

Source [Change the default e‑mail program](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-default-e-mail-program)

Comment: however I don't have in the start option the "amke outlook the deffult program tab"

Comment: Did the first option work? Which version of Windows do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

- Click start
- Type "default programs" in the Start Search box.
- Click Default Programs under Programs in the search results.
- Now click Set your default programs.
- Highlight Microsoft Office Outlook or Microsoft Outlook on the left.
- Click Set this program as default.
- Click OK.

Source: [outlook tips](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How_to_Make_Outlook_Your_Default_Email_Program.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto control panel, type "default programs" without quotes
2. Select **Default Programs** option

[image]

3. Click on **set your default programs** option

[image]

4. Click on **Microsoft Outlook**
5. Click on **Set this program as default**

[image]